# How to use FieldByName to extract nested struct value

Tags: json, go

Here is the struct:

```
type UP struct {
    Rxinfo []struct {
        Gatewayid string    `json:"gatewayID"`
        Uplinkid  string    `json:"uplinkID"`
        Name      string    `json:"name"`
        Time      time.Time `json:"time"`
        Rssi      int       `json:"rssi"`
        Lorasnr   float64   `json:"loRaSNR"`
        Location  struct {
            Latitude  int `json:"latitude"`
            Longitude int `json:"longitude"`
            Altitude  int `json:"altitude"`
        } `json:"location"`
    } `json:"rxInfo"`
    Adr  bool   `json:"adr"`
    Fcnt int    `json:"fCnt"`
    Data string `json:"data"`
}
```

When I code like this:

```golang
    up := UP{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Payload(), &up); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Message could not be parsed (%s): %s", msg.Payload(), err)
    }

    val := reflect.ValueOf(up).FieldByName("Name")
    fmt.Printf("%v",val)
```

It returns `<invalid reflect.Value>`.

Comment: `Name` is a field in a struct contained in a slice.  There can be zero or more values for that struct. Which one do you want to get?

Comment: Sorry sir, I don't get it.  My puzzle is that when I extract data like Adr that is not nested in struct, it will not report an error, but when I extract Name, it does. So I need to adjust the program structure. I don't quite understand what 0 or more values mean.

Comment: You have a slice of the struct with the `Name` field. A slice can have zero or more elements. Take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) if you don't know what a slice is or why slices can have zero or more elements.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the logs return an `<invalid reflect.Value>` error is because the field `Name` is located inside a slice of structs. If you want to get the value of a field from a slice of struct, you have to specify which index of the slice you want to get value from.

For example, your payload looks like this:

```
{
   "rx_info":[
      {
         "gateway_id":"1",
         "up_link_id":"2",
         "name":"sunstrider",
         "time":"2021-05-25T19:37:00Z",
         "rssi":-21,
         "lo_ra_snr":0.342,
         "location":{
            "latitiude":413,
            "longitude":124,
            "altitude":41
         }
      },
      {
         "gateway_id":"2",
         "up_link_id":"4",
         "name":"sunstrider 2",
         "time":"2021-06-25T19:37:00Z",
         "rssi":-41,
         "lo_ra_snr":0.562,
         "location":{
            "latitiude":213,
            "longitude":321,
            "altitude":443
         }
      }
   ],
   "address":true,
   "fcnt":53,
   "data":"this is the data"
}
```

Notice how the field `Name` is inside an object that's inside an array. If your payload looks like this, then your code should look like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

type UP struct {
    RxInfo  []RxInfo `json:"rx_info"`
    Address bool     `json:"address"`
    FCNT    int      `json:"fcnt"`
    Data    string   `json:"data"`
}

type RxInfo struct {
    GatewayID string    `json:"gateway_id"`
    UplinkID  string    `json:"uplink_id"`
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Time      time.Time `json:"time"`
    RSSI      int       `json:"rssi"`
    LoRaSNR   float64   `json:"lo_ra_snr"`
    Location  Location  `json:"location"`
}

type Location struct {
    Latitude  int `json:"latitude"`
    Longitude int `json:"longitude"`
    Altitude  int `json:"altitude"`
}

func main() {
    up := UP{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(payload), &up); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Message could not be parsed (%s): %s", payload, err)
    }

    // because the "Name" field is inside an array, we have to 
    // bind the payload array to an array of a predefined struct
    valSlice := reflect.ValueOf(up).FieldByName("RxInfo").Interface().([]RxInfo)     
    
    // getting the value from the zeroth index
    fmt.Println(valSlice[0].Name)    

    // getting the value from the first index
    fmt.Println(valSlice[1].Name)

    // since your goal is to get the value of a field, I suggest you
    // get the value using the structure of the struct using
    // "dot" operator rather than of using the FieldByName()
    valString := up.RxInfo[0].Name
    fmt.Println(valString)
}
```

Also, a couple of tips to keep your code clean:

- You should always access the value of the payload using the structure of your struct. Only use `reflect.ValueOf(variable).FieldByName("name_of_field")` when you don't know the complete structure of your payload.
- If you have a deeply nested struct, split them up into multiple tiny structs (like my example above) to make it easier to read and maintain.
- Standardize your naming convention. This applies when you're naming variables, structs, struct fields, struct tags, etc. I personally use camel-case for field names and snake-case for json struct tags.